# Possible areas for congruent regions partitioning a plane and containing each a vertex of a lattice.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, number-theory, measure-theory

If the plane is partitioned into congruent regions each of area $A$ and each containing a single vertex of a lattice with fundamental parallelogram of area $F$, is $A\neq F$ possible?

More generally if $\rm{ I\!R}^n$ ($n\ge 1$) is partitioned into congruent regions, each of $n$-volume $A$ and each containing a single vertex of a lattice with fundamental $n-$parallelopiped of $n-$volume F, is $A\neq F$ possible?

This has some similarities with the so far unanswered question here:

[Possible areas for convex regions partitioning a plane and containing each a vertex of a square lattice.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2138807/possible-areas-for-convex-regions-partitioning-a-plane-and-containing-each-a-ver)

but is in fact disjoint. If the regions in the current question are convex, then necessarily $A=F$.$^*$

Also if a region is bounded or if there is a translation between each pair of regions that takes the lattice vertex in the first to that in the second, then again necessarily $A=F$.$^*$

So if there are any such partitions with $A\neq F$, the regions must be unbounded, non-convex and not all similarly situated with respect to their vertex points. Also, in view of Del's comment below, $A$ must be less than $F$.

$^*$ I will post proofs of the indicated assertions if requested.

.

.

.

Small print if any clarification is needed.

A partition of the plane is a set of pairwise disjoint subsets whose union is the whole plane.

Two sets are congruent if there is a 1-1 distance preserving mapping from one onto the other.

My use of the word "region" here is as in *Apostol, Mathematical Analysis*.

> A set in $R^n$ is called a region if it is the union of an open connected set with some, none, or all of its boundary points.

The term "area" (resp. "$n-$volume") can be taken as Lebesgue measure (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure). The value $0$ is acceptable in the measure, but not possible in a partition as described.

The vertices of a lattice are the points $\sum_{i=1}^nn_i{\mathbf b}_i$ for some basis $\{{\mathbf b}_i\}$ and choice of origin, with $n_i\in \mathbb{Z}$. The fundamental parallelogram (resp. $n-$parallelopiped) of the same lattice is the set $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i{\mathbf b}_i$, with $\lambda_i\in [0,1)$.

Comment: Interesting question! $A>F$ can not happen: by truncating each region far enough in the same way, you could obtain disjoint equibounded regions still with area $>A$. Then you find a contradiction: a large ball contains completely all the regions whose vertex lies in a slightly smaller ball; but it doesn't have enough area to contain them.

Comment: @Del - Well it certainly means they can be shrunk to bounded sets with an area $A'>F$, so yes, I think you can say if $A\neq F$ then $A<F$.